# Importing site gives "Security check failed in OnFolderImport" error

Tags: security, import, export

I'm using the [SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) (2.8 beta) and have successfully exported a site. Now I'm trying to import the site and it gives me the following messages in the log and isn't successful:

```
[30-Aug-11 5:34:57 PM] Start Time: 30-Aug-11 5:34:57 PM.
[30-Aug-11 5:34:57 PM] Progress: Initializing Import.
[30-Aug-11 5:35:01 PM] Debug: Security check failed in OnUserGroupExport
[30-Aug-11 5:35:01 PM] Debug: Security check failed in OnUserGroupExport
[30-Aug-11 5:35:01 PM] Progress: Starting content import.
[30-Aug-11 5:35:01 PM] Progress: De-Serializing Objects to Database.
[30-Aug-11 5:35:02 PM] [Folder] [Page Layout] Progress: Importing
[30-Aug-11 5:35:02 PM] [Folder] [Page Layout]   Verbose: Source URL: _catalogs/masterpage/Forms/Page Layout
[30-Aug-11 5:35:02 PM] Debug: Security check failed in OnFolderImport
```

The whole log is filled with `Security check failed in` with

- OnFolderImport
- OnListImport
- OnListItemImport
- OnWebImport
- etc.

I am using an account that has full database control and is part of the Administrators group on the box. This is a standalone installation (not a farm) with the SQL Express install on the same machine as SharePoint.

The Site URL is set to `http://vmdev195/` and the Import Web URL is set to `http://vmdev195:1260/health`. I'd like to take a site from a CMP file and import it to the `health` site at the other port.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm somewhat closer to a solution: I logged on with my own account, under which the objects are owned, exported again, and imported. It worked without the security warnings. But now I don't know where it put the site! It's not at the `http://vmdev195:1260/health` URL; and it might be overwriting the original site.